# In how many ways can he select at least one, but not all, of the shirts?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am lost with another problem.

> Mrs. Polychamise has 15 shirts
> and wishes to donate some of them to
> the church yard sale. She asks Mr. Polychamise to grab some of
> them, and he selects at least one, but not all,
> of them. In how many ways could he have made his selection?

I don't have a good idea on how to go about my logic.
so far I thought about using:
$$
\sum_i^{15} {}_{15}C_i
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Selecting at least one but not all is *exactly* two less than all the possible subsets (the empty set and the full set are not allowed).

Comment: Thank you so much, I finished the answer with this hint.